# Custom docker image for inference

Tags: amazon-sagemaker, amazon-ecr

I've created a docker image web service I'm trying to get to run on SageMaker as an inference service.

I've created an execution role with the following permissions:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::arn:aws:s3:::XXXXX-ai-sagemaker"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::arn:aws:s3:::XXXXX-ai-sagemaker/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "sagemaker:BatchPutMetrics",
                "ecr:GetAuthorizationToken",
                "ecr:ListImages"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability",
                "ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer",
                "ecr:BatchGetImage"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:ecr:eu-central-1:553XXXXXXXX:repository/similarity"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "cloudwatch:PutMetricData",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "cloudwatch:namespace": [
                        "*SageMaker*",
                        "*Sagemaker*",
                        "*sagemaker*"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "logs:CreateLogStream",
                "logs:PutLogEvents",
                "logs:CreateLogGroup",
                "logs:DescribeLogStreams"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:logs:*:*:log-group:/aws/sagemaker/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

I have the docker image hosted on a private repository in `ECR` - The role has permission to pull images from the repository.

When running the following python code:

```py
import boto3
from time import gmtime, strftime

model_name = 'similarity-model' + strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S", gmtime())

image_config = {
    'RepositoryAccessMode': 'Vpc'
}

vpc_config = {
    'SecurityGroupIds': ['sg-1ebfXXXX'],
    'Subnets': ['subnet-8a47XXXX', 'subnet-b707XXX']
}

primary_container = {
    'ContainerHostname': 'ModelContainer',
    'Image': '553XXXXXX.dkr.ecr.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/similarity:latest',
    'ImageConfig': image_config
}
sm = boto3.client('sagemaker')
execution_role_arn = 'arn:aws:iam::553XXXXXX:role/service-role/SageMaker-sagemaker'

try:
    resp = sm.create_model(
        ModelName=model_name,
        PrimaryContainer=primary_container,
        ExecutionRoleArn=execution_role_arn,
        VpcConfig=vpc_config,
    )
except Exception as e:
    print(f'error calling CreateModel operation: {e}')
else:
    print(resp)
```

I recieve the following error from *create_model()*:

`An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the CreateModel operation: Using ECR image "553XXXXXXX.dkr.ecr.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/similarity:latest" with Vpc repository access mode is not supported.`

Any suggestions would be good at this point :)

Comment: I must say you are the first to have such question because Sagemaker is pretty new. Can't you use the interface?

Comment: use the interface how? You cant setup an ECR model using the aws web console as far as I can tell - looking again - i see it

Comment: It seems to me pointless to bring so much effort on a feature without providing even such a fundamental feature.

Comment: @BrunoPeixoto i got the service running using the UI - so you did help a lot, thanks.